# Windows Batch : Execute application with all files in a folder, sorted randomly

Tags: windows, batch-file, media-player

I use media player classic to play videos.
I can make a batch file to play a playlist, like this:

```
mpc.exe video1.avi video2.avi video3.avi ...
```

It works.

Now I would like to make a batch file that plays all videos in a folder sorted randomly.

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below assumes you are playing files from the current directory, and it assumes none of your .avi file names begin with `=`. It wouldn't take much to eliminate those limitations.

If you have too many files in your folder, then eventually the command length will exceed the maximum allowed length of 8191 bytes.

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
for /f "delims==" %%A in ('set file. 2^>nul') do set "%%A="
for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%A in (
  'dir /b /a-d *.avi^|findstr /n "^"'
) do (
  set "file.%%A=%%B"
  set "cnt=%%A"
)
set "cmd=mpc.exe"
for /l %%N in (%cnt% -1 1) do call :buildCmd %%N
%cmd%
exit /b

:buildCmd
set /a N=%random% %% %1
set "skip="
if %N% gtr 0 set "skip=skip=%N%"
for /f "%skip% tokens=1* delims==" %%A in ('set file.') do (
  set cmd=%cmd% "%%B"
  set "%%A="
  exit /b
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The Batch file below will fail if the name of any video file have exclamation marks. This may be fixed, if needed.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Store the file names into an array
set cnt=0
for %%a in (*.avi) do (
   set /A cnt+=1
   set file[!cnt!]=%%a
)

rem Insert the names in the command line in random order
set cmd=mpc.exe
for /L %%a in (%cnt%,-1,1) do (
   set /A i=%%a*!random!/32768+1
   for %%i in (!i!) do set cmd=!cmd! "!file[%%i]!"
   set file[%%i]=!file[%%a]!
)

%cmd%
```

Antonio